Finding a conformal mapping
I am trying to find a conformal map between the regions:
$$\Omega_1 = \{z \,:\, |z| < 2,\, |z - 1| > 1\}, \quad \Omega_2 = \{z\,:\,\text{Im}(z) > 0 ,\, |z - i| > 1\}.$$
Specifically, I want an FLT between these two, so some map $f$ with
$$ f(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d} $$
My attempt is below, honestly I am not at all confident this is correct but I'm a bit lost on how to check. If I am wrong, please let me know where the error is/how to correct it. If I am correct, how can I check/visualise the answer? Plotting the $f(z)$ found below, I can see that for the region $\Omega_1$ the function does always have positive imaginary component, at least.
Inspecting a sketch of two regions, in $\Omega_1$ the two circles meet at $z = 2$. These should map onto the two circles $|z - i|> 1$, and the real axis, which meet at $0$, so $f(2) = 0$. My guess (is this valid/is there a better way to come up with this?) is that $-2$ should become a point at infinity, so $f(-2) = \infty$, and $f(0)$ should lie on the circle $|z - i| > 1$ and on a line connecting $f(2),\,f(-2)$, so set $f(0) = 2i$.
These give me the equations:
$$ \frac{b}{d} = 2i, \quad \frac{2a + b}{2c + d} = 0, \quad \frac{-2a + b}{-2c + d} = \infty $$
We have $-2c + d = 0$ so $d = 2c$, and $2a + b = 0$ so $b = -2a$. Finally, $b/d = -a/c = 2i$, so $a = -2ci$. To obtain solutions, assume $c = 1$. Then $d = 2$, $a = -2i$, $b = 4i$, and:
$$ f(z) = \frac{-2i(z - 2)}{z + 2}. $$
